# Raphael js, animate on multiple connected path

Tags: javascript, raphael

how can i make animate from one path to another path, but path still connected.

this my source code. if on path1 still working, but on path2 not started from first point.

```
        var obj;
        var path1
        var path2;


        var canvas = Raphael("canvas", 620, 420);
        window.onload = function() {

            obj = canvas.circle(100, 200, 10);                

            path1 = canvas.path("M100 200L200 200");
            path2 = canvas.path("M200 200L400 100");

            window.setInterval("method_animasi()", 10); 
        };

        var counter = 0;
        var position;
        function method_animasi(){

            position = path1.getPointAtLength(counter);   

            if(position.x == 200 && position.y == 200){
                position = path2.getPointAtLength(counter);
            }
            obj.attr({cx: position.x, cy: position.y});    

            counter++;
        };
```

you can see on http://jsfiddle.net/jhohannespurba/cE26g/

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that with incredible ease by using a single, complex path instead of two single-command paths.  For instance, define your path1 as

```
path1 = canvas.path( [  "M", 100, 200,
                        "L", 200, 200,
                        "R", 220, 180, 220, 160, 250, 150,
                        "L", 400, 100,
                        "A", 120, 120, 150, 0, 1, 450, 180,
                        "L", 350, 240,
                        "R", 320, 280, 240, 220,
                        "L", 100, 280,
                        "R", 50, 240, 100, 200 ]);
```

Note how the commands lead from one to the next.  "R" is notation for the Catmull-Rom spline curve, which simplifies curved changes of direction, and "A" is the arc command.  You can check out the [SVG specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html) for paths if you want -- there's a lot of other stuff you can do.  It's also worth noting that you can compile your paths using arrays (this is a Raphael utility), which is particularly useful if you're using variables in your paths.

Next, just adjust your animation loop to use the single path.

```
function method_animasi() 
{
    position = path1.getPointAtLength(counter);

    obj.attr( {cx: position.x, cy: position.y } );

    counter++;
    if ( counter >= path1.getTotalLength() )
    {
        counter = 0;  // This will take us back to the beginning and start the whole animation all over again, yay!
    }
};
```

And that's that!  Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kevindivdbyzero/bAsCT/

Comment: Thank you Kevin, but i wanna make object go to random path after path1 finished. maybe you can see this, sorry if my english not good..   http://jsfiddle.net/jhohannespurba/cE26g/1/

Comment: Hi Jhohannes, sorry it took me so long to get back to you.  Check out my blog post: http://code.voidblossom.com/using-raphael-to-animate-objects-along-path-networks/.  It might give you some useful ideas.

Comment: Thank you agin Kevin, i'll try soon, i got the technuiqe replace value on the path and set counter to 0 .. but i will try your code, hopping problem is clear... hehe.. cheers.. :D